# CMake configure and generate LMMS errors

Tags: qt, cmake, build, configure, lmms

I'm trying to configure and build LMMS from sources following the guide:
https://github.com/LMMS/lmms/wiki/dependencies-windows#windows-msvc

I have
Windows 7 x64
msvc 2019
Qt 5.15.1 both x32 and x64  with Qt Creator 4.13.2
CMake  3.16.1

First, at the end of (I use `--triplet x64-windows` option)

```
.\vcpkg install fftw3 libsamplerate libsndfile sdl2 --triplet x64-windows
```

I get

```
 ...
 The package fftw3:x64-windows provides CMake targets:

find_package(FFTW3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE FFTW3::fftw3)

find_package(FFTW3f CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE FFTW3::fftw3f)

find_package(FFTW3l CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE FFTW3::fftw3l)

The package libsndfile:x64-windows provides CMake targets:

find_package(SndFile CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE SndFile::sndfile)

The package sdl2:x64-windows provides CMake targets:

find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2 SDL2::SDL2main)
```

Do the captions "CONFIG REQUIRED" require some actions from me before the next steps?

---

As the instruction wrote, I add **vcpkg** path to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING`:

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_PREFIX};g:\audio_sources\lmms\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows
```

Then in Qt Creator when opening CMakeLists.txt I get:

```
Running C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -S G:/audio_sources/lmms -B C:/Users/Ber/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-IYdlTJ/qtc-cmake-UUUBKujd -GNinja "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:String=Debug" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=C:/Qt/5.15.1/msvc2019_64;g:\audio_sources\lmms\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows" "-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=C:/Qt/5.15.1/msvc2019_64/bin/qmake.exe" in C:\Users\Ber\AppData\Local\Temp\QtCreator-IYdlTJ\qtc-cmake-UUUBKujd.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29110.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29110.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:15 (CMAKE_POLICY):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0050 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Warning at cmake/modules/PluginList.cmake:104 (message):
  Compiling with MSVC.  The following plugins are not available:
  LadspaEffect;zynaddsubfx
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:21 (INCLUDE)



Checking submodules...
-- Skipping plugins/zynaddsubfx/zynaddsubfx matches "plugins/zynaddsubfx/zynaddsubfx" (absent in PLUGIN_LIST)
-- Skipping plugins/LadspaEffect/calf/veal matches "plugins/LadspaEffect/calf/veal" (absent in PLUGIN_LIST)
-- Skipping plugins/LadspaEffect/swh/ladspa matches "plugins/LadspaEffect/swh/ladspa" (absent in PLUGIN_LIST)
-- Skipping plugins/LadspaEffect/tap/tap-plugins matches "plugins/LadspaEffect/tap/tap-plugins" (absent in PLUGIN_LIST)
-- Checking qt5-x11embed...
--   Found src/3rdparty/qt5-x11embed/CMakeLists.txt
-- Checking rpmalloc...
--   Found src/3rdparty/rpmalloc/rpmalloc/configure.py
-- Checking game-music-emu...
--   Found plugins/FreeBoy/game-music-emu/CMakeLists.txt
-- Checking adplug...
--   Found plugins/OpulenZ/adplug/Makefile.am
-- Checking exprtk...
--   Found plugins/Xpressive/exprtk/Makefile
-- Checking weakjack...
--   Found src/3rdparty/weakjack/weakjack/.gitignore
-- Checking mingw-std-threads...
--   Found src/3rdparty/mingw-std-threads/LICENSE
-- Checking wiki...
--   Found doc/wiki/Home.md
-- Checking ringbuffer...
--   Found src/3rdparty/ringbuffer/CMakeLists.txt
-- Checking carla...
--   Found plugins/carlabase/carla/Makefile
-- Done validating submodules.

-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.24.0.windows.2") 

Configuring LMMS
--------------------------
* Project version             : 1.2.3-735+gf5d0524b1
*   Major version             : 1
*   Minor version             : 2
*   Release version           : 3
*   Stage version             : 735+gf5d0524b1
*   Build version             : 0
*

Optional Version Usage:
--------------------------
*   Override version:           -DFORCE_VERSION=x.x.x-x
*   Ignore Git information:     -DFORCE_VERSION=internal

PROCESSOR: AMD64
-- Target host is 64 bit
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - not found
-- Looking for include file semaphore.h
-- Looking for include file semaphore.h - not found
-- Looking for include file unistd.h
-- Looking for include file unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/ipc.h
-- Looking for include file sys/ipc.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/shm.h
-- Looking for include file sys/shm.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/time.h
-- Looking for include file sys/time.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/times.h
-- Looking for include file sys/times.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sched.h
-- Looking for include file sched.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/soundcard.h
-- Looking for include file sys/soundcard.h - not found
-- Looking for include file soundcard.h
-- Looking for include file soundcard.h - not found
-- Looking for include file fcntl.h
-- Looking for include file fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for include file sys/ioctl.h - not found
-- Looking for include file ctype.h
-- Looking for include file ctype.h - found
-- Looking for include file string.h
-- Looking for include file string.h - found
-- Looking for include file process.h
-- Looking for include file process.h - found
-- Looking for include file locale.h
-- Looking for include file locale.h - found
-- Found Qt translations in C:/Qt/5.15.1/msvc2019_64/translations
-- Found SndFile: G:/audio_sources/lmms/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/sndfile.lib  
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found SDL2: G:/audio_sources/lmms/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/SDL2.lib  
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find Lame (missing: LAME_INCLUDE_DIRS LAME_LIBRARIES) 
-- Looking for vorbis_bitrate_addblock in vorbis
-- Looking for vorbis_bitrate_addblock in vorbis - not found
-- Found OggVorbis: G:/audio_sources/lmms/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/ogg.lib;G:/audio_sources/lmms/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/vorbis.lib;G:/audio_sources/lmms/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/vorbisfile.lib;G:/audio_sources/lmms/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/vorbisenc.lib
-- Found FFTW: G:/audio_sources/lmms/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include  
-- Found OpenGL: opengl32   
-- Could NOT find FLTK (missing: FLTK_LIBRARIES FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR FLTK_FLUID_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find Wine (missing: WINE_CXX WINE_LIBRARIES WINE_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
-- Found SAMPLERATE: G:/audio_sources/lmms/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/libsamplerate-0.lib  
-- Looking for include file sys/mman.h
-- Looking for include file sys/mman.h - not found
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Failed
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED - Success
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Bash competion is not supported on this platform.
-- Could NOT find UnixCommands (missing: BASH CP GZIP MV RM TAR) 

Installation Summary
--------------------
* Install Directory           : C:/Program Files (x86)/lmms

Supported audio interfaces
--------------------------
* ALSA                        : <not supported on this platform>
* JACK                        : <not supported on this platform>
* OSS                         : <not found or not supported on this platform>
* Sndio                       : 
* PortAudio                   : not found, please install portaudio19-dev (or similar, version >= 1.9) ;if you require PortAudio support
* libsoundio                  : <disabled in this release>
* PulseAudio                  : <not supported on this platform>
* SDL                         : OK, using SDL2

Supported MIDI interfaces
-------------------------
* ALSA                        : <not supported on this platform>
* OSS                         : <not found or not supported on this platform>
* Sndio                       : 
* JACK                        : <not supported on this platform>
* WinMM                       : OK
* AppleMidi                   : <not supported on this platform>

Supported file formats for project export
-----------------------------------------
* WAVE                        : OK
* FLAC                        : OK
* OGG/VORBIS                  : OK
* MP3/Lame                    : not found, please install libmp3lame-dev (or similar)

Optional plugins
----------------
* Lv2 plugins                 : not found, requires pkg-config
* SUIL for plugin UIs         : not found, requires pkg-config
* ZynAddSubFX instrument      : not found, please install fltk
* Carla Patchbay & Rack       : OK (weak linking enabled)
* SoundFont2 player           : not found, libfluidsynth-dev (or similar);is highly recommended
* Stk Mallets                 : not found, please install libstk0-dev (or similar) ;if you require the Mallets instrument
* VST-instrument hoster       : OK
* VST-effect hoster           : OK
* CALF LADSPA plugins         : OK
* CAPS LADSPA plugins         : OK
* CMT LADSPA plugins          : OK
* TAP LADSPA plugins          : OK
* SWH LADSPA plugins          : OK
* GIG player                  : not found, libgig needed for decoding .gig files

Developer options
-----------------------------------------
* Debug FP exceptions         : Disabled


-----------------------------------------------------------------
IMPORTANT:
after installing missing packages, remove CMakeCache.txt before
running cmake again!
-----------------------------------------------------------------



-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Ber/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-IYdlTJ/qtc-cmake-UUUBKujd
Elapsed time: 00:35.
```

Among other things, among the messages I see the lines

```
The following plugins are not available:
      LadspaEffect;zynaddsubfx
```

While there are both `LadspaEffect` and `zynaddsubfx` source folders in the `plugins` dir.

**What I am doing wrong?**
Whether I really need to install `pkg-config` in addition to `vcpkg` ? Can I use `pkg-config-lite-0.28-1` ?

Comment: The policy message is for the developer of the library.

Comment: ***Compiling with MSVC.  The following plugins are not available:
  LadspaEffect;zynaddsubfx*** I expect that this is intentional. The developers are telling you that these are disabled because they don't work with msvc.

Comment: ***I really need to install pkg-config in addition to vcpkg ?*** I would say on msvc no.

Comment: The documentation states this: ***Warning, MSVC building is still experimental. Some plugins aren't available when compiling with MSVC.***

Comment: ***What I am doing wrong?*** Nothing.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, but it not only miss some plugins, but not compiling at all. But I have downloaded binary version of LMMS and decide that it is bad tool.

Comment: In most situations CMake just generates project files but does not build anything. I think you have to compile with the build files that were generated at ***C:/Users/Ber/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-IYdlTJ/qtc-cmake-UUUBKujd***

Comment: @drescherjm yes I know that configuring is not a build

Answer (score 0):

As someone who is involved with the LMMS team, i can say that ladspa amd zyn are disabled intentionally (zyn support was recently added though). The reason for this is that these plug ins contains some Linux/GCC only workarounds. The windows binaries are actually cross compiled from ubuntu. If you wanna know more, join the discord (link in LMMS website).

Edit : as of now, I have opened a Pull Request to add LADSPA support too. Come back once that one gets merged.